# How to add adjacent cells in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am looking for a way to add up cells under a name. For instance, I am trying to tally all of the assists the character "Annie" got in a few different games of League of Legends.

[image: Spreadsheet image]

I am looking for a way to search for a name (which shows up multiple times) and then count adjacent cells.

Comment: Not sure I understand - could you specify what your expected result would be for "Annie"?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
=sumifs(B7:B43,B4:B40,"Annie")
```

and then add for other columns if required.

Answer (score 1):

I think the use of a little script is best served here.

### Code

```
function getAssists(range, name, skill) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var data = ss.getRange(range).getValues();
  var objTypes = {"Kills": 1, "Assist": 2};

  var totalAssists = 0, type = objTypes[skill];
  for(var i = 0, iLen = data.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    for(var j = 0, jLen = data[0].length; j < jLen; j++) {
      if(data[i][j] === name) {
        totalAssists += data[i+type][j];
      }
    }
  }
  return totalAssists;
}
```

### Explained

The first parameter of the custom function (*range*) determines which data range to use and the second (*name*) which name to look for. The last will select the skill to sum up. If the name has been found, then add the corresponding skill to the total.

### Screenshot

[image]

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[Total Assists for Annie](https://docs.google.com/a/familietuinstra.nl/spreadsheets/d/1ldVqxWy1dKfmiMTb-QilWnUwGdKS4A4Q0iDOP1-NIbw/edit?usp=sharing)**
Make a copy or add the code under *Tools > Script editor* from the menu.